# Can I idolize a movie star?

Tags: halal-haram, shirk, behavior

Most of my friends say that following a movie star is not accepted in Islam.
Being a Muslim, is it haram or considered as a sin for idolizing one?

Answer (score 1):

***Following*** is a vague term. What exactly are you following? If you saw that movie star in a certain outfit and you like that outfit, you can wear it too as long as it fulfills Islamic rules of clothing and modesty. Etc. etc.

One must obey Prophet Muhammad (SAW). But when one starts to love Prophet Muhammad (SAW), one would not just obey his (SAW) orders, but will try to follow him (SAW) in every aspect.

If your belief gets to this high level (mentioned in 2nd para of my answer), then you cannot *idolize* or *follow* any other human.

Answer (score 0):

Assalaamualaikum. First of all , what do you mean by term "idolizing" . If you mean worship , it is shirk.
Well i guess it means the following. Movie Stars are usually part of the Haraam industry like "Music , Party ,Alcohol ,Zina ,Riba(interest)," and so on . Idolizing means to imitate the person in as much percentage as possible. And if you look above , the innocent person might end up doing all of the above prohibitions.
 The best idol (i.e to imitate in character) is our beloved Prophet Muhammad Sallallaho alayhi wassallam.Lets Follow him ..Success lies there. Idolizing means to follow completely and every person isn't perfect. So idolizing could mean inheriting the bad habits too.. If you follow only the good habits of a movie star, no problem .. Just maintain the good character.
If the answer was still insufficient , please mention it in the comments and i'll elaborate further.. And Allah knows best! Barakallahu feekum.

Recommended Watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvPU8Guj0fg